# Unable to add performance counters of Oracle OLEDB provider

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oledb, odp.net, performancecounter

At my server, I am using SqlClient to connect to SQL Server, Oledb for old apps connecting with Oracle and ODP.NET for new apps connecting with Oracle.

I am seeing in perf counters:

1. .NET Data Provider for Oracle
2. .NET Data Provider for Sql Server
3. ODP.NET Managed

But I can only add and see counters of *.NET Data Provider for Sql Server* and *ODP.NET* while the *.NET Data Provider for Oracle* (I mean `System.Data.Oledb`) is not working.

*Source:*

- [Monitoring OleDbConnection pool](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/monitoring-oledbconnection-pool.1245649/)

> The OleDb provider does not expose performance counters.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

> The OleDb provider does not expose performance counters.

**Unfortunately, This is True**.

But on the other hand the three providers you have mentioned have performance counters:

1. .NET Data Provider for Oracle
2. .NET Data Provider for Sql Server
3. ODP.NET Managed

## (1,2) .NET Data Provider for Oracle and .NET Data Provider for Sql Server

The [.NET Data Provider for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) is not the `System.Data.OLEDB` provider it is the `System.Data.OracleClient` Provider and it has performance counters. 
Based on [Performance Counters in ADO.NET official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters):

> ADO.NET 2.0 introduced expanded support for performance counters that includes support for both **System.Data.SqlClient** and **System.Data.OracleClient**.

And in [System.Data.OracleClient Namespace documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) they mentioned that:

> The System.Data.OracleClient namespace is the .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle.

### So, What is System.Data.OLEDB?

Referring to [System.Data.OleDb Namespace official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The System.Data.OleDb namespace is the.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB.

**And it doesn't looks like Microsoft has mentioned anything related to this Provider when talking about performance counters.**

## (3) Oracle Data Provider for .NET

Referring to [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15296_01/doc.111/e15167/InstallPerformanceCounters.htm#CIHEGICI):

> Installing Oracle Data Provider for .NET creates a set of **performance counters** on the target system. These performance counters are published by **ODP.NET** for each ODP.NET client application. These performance counters can be viewed using Windows Performance Monitor (Perfmon).

---

**Similar issue link**

- [Can't seem to add sqlclient counters to perfmon](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8464fee7-9f9f-4173-b5d9-8142306a7d80/cant-seem-to-add-sqlclient-counters-to-perfmon?forum=adodotnetdataproviders0)